# Possible to give Airport wifi extender a custom wifi name?

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I have two recent Airport Extremes and a Netgear router (with wifi turned off).
I'd like to connect one of the Airports to the Netgear via ethernet, and have that
Airport provide a wifi network called ALPHA. Then I'd like to use the second
Airport to extend the ALPHA network such that the extended wifi is named BRAVO.

I've looked at the Airport Utility and I get the impression that if an existing
Airport wifi network is extended using a second Airport, the extension wifi will
have the same name as the source wifi from the first Airport: that is, ALPHA with no option to use the name BRAVO.

However, I may be wrong. Is there to way to give the second extender the wifi
name BRAVO?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the **base station name** in AirPort Utility by following these steps:

1. Open AirPort Utility
2. Click on the AirPort of whose name you want to change
3. Click `Enter Password` and enter the password if necessary
4. If this isn't necessary, click `Edit`
5. Navigate to the `Base Station` tab of the menu
6. Edit the name, then hit `Update`

**But in terms of changing the Wi-Fi name**, this is not possible unless you give the AirPort its own network, instead of extending an existing one. It will use the same name as the source network, like you said.